# Spring Security Oauth: migration from xml to annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, annotations, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to migrate from xml to annotations. But I can't correctly configure endpoint /oauth/token - it doesn't accept my params for POST query.

Request:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&client_secret=secret&client_id=testclient&username=root&password=password" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

Log:

```
2014-09-07 16:33:39 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2014-09-07 16:33:39 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:194 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2014-09-07 16:33:39 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:310 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2014-09-07 16:33:39 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@302753d0, returned: -1
2014-09-07 16:33:39 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:165 - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
```

XML (worked correctly) :

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
      authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>
```

Annotations version:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer() {
    return new AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.authenticationEntryPoint(customEntryPoint());
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore());
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager());
            endpoints.clientDetailsService(clientDetailsService());
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService());
        }
    };
}


@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new MD5PasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint customEntryPoint() {
    OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
    oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint.setRealmName("springsec/client");
    oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint.setTypeName("Basic");
    return oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint;
}

@Bean
public TokenStoreDao tokenStoreDao() {
    return new TokenStoreDaoImpl();
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    MongoTokenStore tokenStore = new MongoTokenStore();
    tokenStore.setTokenStoreDao(tokenStoreDao());
    return tokenStore;
}


@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthenticationManager oAuth2AuthenticationManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();
    DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    oAuth2AuthenticationManager.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
    return oAuth2AuthenticationManager;
}

@Bean
public ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService() {
    return new OAuthClienDetailsService();
}

@Bean
public ClientDetailsUserDetailsService clientDetailsUserDetailsService() {
    return new ClientDetailsUserDetailsService(clientDetailsService());
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() throws Exception {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(clientDetailsUserDetailsService());
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    authenticationProvider.afterPropertiesSet();
    return authenticationProvider;
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

**`.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();`**

```
@Bean
public AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer() {
    return new AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(customEntryPoint())
                    .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
        }
```